# android GridView, ListView and WebView in ScrollView

Tags: java, android, gridview, scrollview

I'm implementing mail application for Android. I need to display mail content in ScrollView. The problem is I also need to display attachment as image backed GridView or ListView. Since it is not recommended to put aScrollable layout in ScrollView, how to organize my layout to have adapter based views inside ScrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to organize my layout to have adapter based views inside ScrollView?

You don't.

> I need to display mail content in ScrollView.

Why? Why not display it in a non-selectable first row of the `ListView`? That way, it and the rest of the list scroll in unison. Remember that an `Adapter` can provide different row types, with different layouts, for different rows (via `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`). So you can have the first row be the message, with the rest of the rows being attachments and such.

Or, make the mail content scrollable in its own `ScrollView`, but have the attachments shown separately.

Comment: @cubesoft: I have no idea what you are referring to. What "child view"?

Comment: What if the listview item will be a list view?

Comment: @cubesoft: That is not possible, nor would it be necessary, as the rows of the inner `ListView` could just as easily be rows of the "outer" `ListView`.